# Search steam store by full audio language

Tags: steam

I am trying to filter all games in the steam store by full language audio. Steam makes it easy to search for games with interface translations but I cannot find a way on the steam site nor any external service to only show games with full audio translations. It is listed very clearly in the steam store page for each game so I find it surprising that there is no obvious way to do this.

Is it possible?

Comment: (Since this was bumped) There still doesn't appear to be an option to search for anything besides Interface language in 2017.

Comment: Your best bet would likely be to request this feature @ [https://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/](https://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/).

Comment: You can use steamdb to search by the language key, but it doesn't appear to differentiate between the language for interface, subtitle, or full audio. https://steamdb.info/search/?a=app_keynames&type=-1&keyname=252&operator=1&keyvalue=chinese

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple answer; not yet.